# resize multiple images in php without exceeding memory limit

Tags: php, image-resizing, memory-limit

I am currently trying to get a form which will allow multiple images to be uploaded and resized on the server using PHP. Each uploaded image by the client is around 2.5mb in size.

I am currently using the `move_uploaded_file()` function.

There are no issues to move the files onto the server. The problem arises when I try to crop. Having not **ImageMagick** on my host I am using this setup (not all the code just what's relevant, this is in a loop with `$width` etc. changing for the different crop sizes)

```
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
imagejpeg($image_p, $output_filename, 80);
```

As it stands this will only work for 2 images. If there is 3 or more submitted I get a 'memory exhausted' error. I have researched into this as my memory limit is 120mb. Apparently the `imagecreatefromjpeg` function uses a lot of memory, especially if the file has a large resolution (which mine does - hence why I need them cropped/resized).

Does anyone know of a more efficient approach to this task? I have researched on google but everyone uses the same technique I am.

Comment: Have you tried using _imagedestroy_ for original (`$image`) and resized (`$image_p`) after you done processing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [imagedestroy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagedestroy.php) to clear any memory associated with $image and $image_p :

```
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
imagejpeg($image_p, $output_filename, 80);
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($image_p);
```